# Sharding strategy for solr

Tags: solr, sharding

How must i do scharding in `SOLR`, in order to write documents only to the nodes that have enough RAM and HDD?
Now, i have signature based sharding strategy, which works as calculating signature value by specific document fields, and then document distributes by master acoording to the value to appropriate node(slave).

For example, if my existing nodes does not have enought RAM or HDD space, i want to add new node, so i just add it, without reindexing and new documents are written to the new node. So, how to implement such a strategy?

Comment: why your signature based sharding strategy not working? if you choose the correct field to calculate the signature then every shard should have almost same RAM and HDD usage. how come your shard have different RAM and HDD in first place?